# docker build apt-get update failed with custom network

Tags: networking, docker, build

Can somebody help me get apt-get working when docker build image.

It works with docker0 bridge. But when I add my own bridge as :

```
docker network create --gateway=192.168.0.253 --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --ip-range=192.168.0.128/25 \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge"="true" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc"="true" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"="true" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="192.168.0.254" \
-o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="br0" \
-o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu"="1500" \
-d bridge mynet
```

linked with /etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
       bridge_ports enp2s0
       bridge_fd 0
       bridge_stp off
       bridge_maxwait 0
       address 192.168.0.253
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.0.0
       gateway 192.168.0.254
       dns-nameservers 212.27.40.240 212.27.40.241
```

My docker build failed

```
Step 4 : RUN apt-get update
     ---> Running in 4edfcd4885fe
    Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
      Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' ....
```

But apt-get work fine with :

```
docker run -it --network=mynet --ip=192.168.0.130 --hostname=test --name test ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

How can I solve my build ?

Thanks

Comment: How you issue docker build?

Comment: docker build --file ./test.dockerfile -t test-img .

Comment: Ok I can understand you need an specific network setup for container running, but why you need it for docker build? If you need internet access you can setup a proxy and for dns you can specify what dns you need to use

Comment: I understand my problem : docker build... use docker0 but this bridge is broken by my own bridge "mynet"

Comment: Is it possible to you to build in another machine or virtual machine?